# plotly graph objects persistent data labels when clicking the graph

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, plot-annotations, grouped-bar-chart

I'm generating a graph:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
```

[image: image1]

When I click on a data point I get the x,y data as shown, but as soon as I move the mouse pointer to a different data point then the other disappears.

[image: img2]

I want to have both points appear on the graph in the same image at the same time so that I can compare them.  Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: i don't think there is any way to do this in plotly natively. if you would consider a `plotly-dash` based solution, then this is possible (something like what you see [here](https://dash.plotly.com/interactive-graphing)) – if you are interested, i could write up a sample solution for you that would allow for text annotations to be toggled when you click on certain bars